# Where does the formula for the moment of inertia come from?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I think I 'understand' the concept of moment of inertia, but I don't see why it is proportional to r^2 (for a given point). Is the equation just empirical?

Comment: It comes from the definition of angular momentum when you enforce the form $L = I\omega$

Comment: It also comes from Newton's 2nd law in a rotating reference frame.

Answer (score 2):

If we apply a force $F$ to a mass $m$ then the acceleration is given by Newton's second law:

$$ F = ma $$

and for angular motion we expect a similar equation:

$$ T = I\ddot{\theta} $$

where $T$ is the torque and $I$ is the moment of inertia.

Now suppose we are considering angular motion about a point $P$ a distance $r$ away measured perpendicular to the force:

[image]

The torque about the point $P$ is:

$$ T = Fr \tag{1} $$

The angular acceleration about $P$ is:

$$ \ddot{\theta} = \frac{a}{r} = \frac{F/m}{r} $$

and using equation (1) to substitute for $F$ gives:

$$ \ddot{\theta} = \frac{T}{mr^2} $$

Comparing this with our expected equation for angular acceleration:

$$ T = I\ddot{\theta} $$

We get:

$$ I= mr^2 $$