# Where does the formula for the moment of inertia $I = \int r^2 dm$ come from?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, history, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I've just learned about moments of inertia in my physics I class, $I=\int{r^2dm}$. The math involving moments of inertia in relation to torque and angular momentum is clear to me. I'm looking for some intuition towards where the definition/idea of moments of inertia comes from? Where do we obtain that the moment of inertia of a point mass $I=mr^2$?

I'm interested in the logical development of these ideas.

Comment: Are you interested in a historical development or a logical one that may not follow the history?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Why is moment of inertia dependent on $r^2$ and not on $r$ ? (physical reason)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149796) or [Where does the formula for the moment of inertia come from?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/239006)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider linear acceleration, governed by $F = ma$. If you have a system with many particles, and want to accelerate a system as a whole, the inertia depends on the total mass
$$m_{\text{tot}} = \sum m_i = \int dm$$
where I just converted the sum over masses into an integral.

Now consider a single particle with mass $m$ rotating at radius $r$. Using $\tau = F r$ and $a = r\alpha$, the relationship between torque and angular acceleration is
$$F = m a \quad \to \quad \frac{\tau}{r} = mr \alpha \quad \to \quad \tau = (mr^2) \alpha.$$
We define the moment of inertia to be $I = \tau/\alpha$, analogous to $m = F/a$. Then we see the moment of inertia of a particle is $mr^2$.

Now suppose you want to make a system rotate as a whole. Since each individual particle contributes a moment of inertia of $m_i r_i^2$, the total moment of inertia is just the sum,
$$I_{\text{tot}} = \sum m_i r_i^2 = \int r^2 dm.$$
That's where the formula comes from.

Comment: I just edited the question. If you are able would you mind adding to your answer to explain where the idea that $I=mr^2$ comes from?

Comment: @theideasmith Sure, done!

Comment: You're missing a relevant element - $\vec{F}_{\mathrm{ext}} = m \vec{a}_{\mathrm{center\ of\ mass}}$ is about the rate of change of of the first moment:$$\vec{r}_{\mathrm{center\ of\ mass}} = \frac{\sum_{i} m_i \vec{r}_i}{\sum_{i} m_i}.$$ The numerator is the first moment, $I$ is related to the second moments.

Comment: @SeanLake You're right, I was just considering the special case where all particles in the first system move the same way, to simplify notation a bit.

Answer (score 2):

[knzhou](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/83398/knzhou) has explicitly showed in his [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/290057/36790) how the form $\displaystyle\int r^2~\mathrm dm$ came to picture. So, I'll be not writing the same thing again. Nevertheless, since, OP is interested in the "logical development" of the idea, I deem it worthy to add a brief discussion on moment of inertia as a second-rank tensor in a more general case so that OP might get a view of the whole topic in short.

---

### Introduction:

The angular momentum $\mathbf L$ of a rigid body with respect to a certain stationary point is expressed as:

$$\begin{align}\mathbf L &= \sum_i \mathbf r_i\times (m_i\mathbf v_i)\\ & =\sum_i \mathbf r_i \times m_i (\boldsymbol \omega \times \mathbf r_i)\end{align}$$ where $\mathbf r_i$ is the distance of the $i$ th particle from the fixed point.

Using the identity $\mathbf A\times \mathbf B\times \mathbf C= \mathbf B(\mathbf  A\cdot \mathbf C)- \mathbf C(\mathbf A\cdot \mathbf B),$ we get $$\mathbf L = \sum_i \left[m_i~\boldsymbol \omega r_i^2 - m_i \mathbf r_i(\mathbf r_i\cdot \boldsymbol \omega)\right]\tag I$$

From $\rm (I)$ we get the $x$ component of $\mathbf L$ as

$$L_x = \sum_i\left[ m_i(r_i^2 -x_i^2)~\omega_x - m_ix_iy_i~\omega_y- m_ix_iz_i~\omega_z\right]$$

So, $L_z$ is a linear function each component of angular velocity.

Thus, $\mathbf L$ is linearly transformed from $\boldsymbol \omega\,.$

This can be expressed as $$\mathbf L = \mathsf I\boldsymbol\omega\tag{II}$$

where $\sf I$ is an operator which linearly transforms $\boldsymbol\omega$ to $\mathbf L\,.$ That is,

$$L_i = \sum_j ~I_{ij}~\omega_j$$

$$\therefore ~~~~~~~~~ \mathsf I \equiv \begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy}& I_{xz}\\ I_{yx}& I_{yy}& I_{yz}\\ I_{zx}& I_{zy}& I_{zz} \end{bmatrix} $$ where $$I_{ij} = \sum_ i m_i (r_i^2 ~\delta_{ij} - r_ir_j)\tag{III}$$ and $\mathbf L$ and $\boldsymbol\omega$ are column matrices.

### Ellipsoid of Inertia:

From $\rm(III),$ it can be concluded that $I_{xy} = I_{yx};$ this means $\sf I$ is a symmetric matrix.

> Any symmetric linear operator can be expressed in a unique diagonal form (the diagonal elements are unique but the order of the elements may be different) by orthogonal transformation of coordinates. The corresponding *principle* axes will be unique and orthogonal.

Now, kinetic energy $\textrm{KE}$ of the rigid body is $$\begin{align}\textrm{KE}&=\frac12 \sum_i m_i (\boldsymbol \omega \times\mathbf r_i)\cdot (\boldsymbol \omega \times\mathbf r_i)\\ &=\frac12\sum_i  m_i \boldsymbol\omega\cdot (\mathbf r_i\times (\boldsymbol \omega \times\mathbf r_i))\\&= \frac12\boldsymbol\omega\cdot \mathbf L\\ &= \frac12 \boldsymbol\omega\cdot \mathsf I\boldsymbol \omega~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\textrm{using}~\mathrm{II})\end{align}$$ which on expanding gives $$\begin{align}T &=\frac12( I_{xx}\omega_x^2 + I_{yy}\omega_y^2 + I_{zz}\omega_z^2) + \frac12\sum_i\sum_j(I_{ij}\omega_i\omega_j) \\ &= \frac12\sum_{i}I_{ii}~\omega_i^2 + (I_{xy}\omega_x\omega_y + I_{yz}\omega_y\omega_z + I_{zx}\omega_z\omega_x)~~~~~~~~~~~~~(I_{xy}= I_{yx}) \end{align}\,.$$

Now, when $x,y,z$ are the *principle* axes, then $$T=\frac12( I_{xx}\omega_x^2 + I_{yy}\omega_y^2 + I_{zz}\omega_z^2)\,. $$ 
The quadratic equation implies that the locus of angular velocities for which $\mathrm{KE} $ is constant must be an ellipsoid since energy is always positive.

This means all the off-diagonal elements of $\mathsf I$ will be zero and $\mathbf L \parallel\boldsymbol{\omega}\,.$

So, in principle axes, only the diagonal coefficients of moment of inertia  are non-zero viz. $$L_i = I_{ii}\omega_i^2\,.$$

---

### References:

$\bullet$ *Classical Mechanics* by *Goldstein*.